# Read a reference cursor which returns a column of string values

Tags: java, jdbc, cursor

I am trying to read ref cursors, which returns only one column, a list of string data.

How can I do it java? Do I have to iterate through each resultset or is there any way so that I could get the entire column in one go. I have 5 ref cursor from the procedure.

```
rs1= (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(1);
rs2= (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(2);
rs3= (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(3);


while(rs1.next()){
      list1.add(rs1.getString(1));
  }

while(rs2.next()){
      list2.add(rs2.getString(1));
  }

while(rs3.next()){
      list3.add(rs3.getString(1));
  }
```

Comment: You should try adding any relevant code that you've tried so far, so that we can help.

Comment: There is an option to edit your question- you should add any code to your question rather than in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this can help :

```
        ResultSet result=null ;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ArrayList yourlist = new ArrayList();
        try
        {
            String queryString = "select yourfield from ....";
             result = pstmt.executeQuery();

            while(result.next())
            {
                yourlist.add(result.getInt("yourfield")); //if you are returning varchar so use getString

            }

        }    
        catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString() );
                    }

        finally
        {
            if(result!=null)
                result.close();
            if(pstmt!=null)
                pstmt.close();
        }
```

Comment: the procedure is returning three ref_cursor. Each having only a list of strings. is there anyother way to optimise the code